# Descending Game Condition and Transfinite induction

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory, surreal-numbers

I am having a bit of trouble understanding the proof of Conway induction.

Definition: **Descending Game condition**: There does not exist an infinite sequence of games $G^i=(L^i,R^i)$ with $G^{i+1}\subset L^i \cup R^i$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Theorem: **Conway Induction**: Let $P$ be a property which games might have,
such that any game $G$ has property $P$ whenever all left and right options of $G$ have
this property. Then every game has property $P$.

PROOF: Suppose there is a game $G$ which does not satisfy $P$. If all left and right
options of $G$ satisfy $P$, then $G$ does also by hypothesis, so there is an option $G_0$
of $G$ which does not satisfy $P$. Continuing this argument inductively, we obtain a
sequence $G,G_0,G_1, . . .$ of games, each an option of its predecessor, which violates
the Descending Game Condition. Note that formalizing this argument needs the
Axiom of Choice.

**ISSUE**: Why does the sequence have to be infinite. If we reach a game with empty options won't the sequence be finite. Say we start with the game $2\equiv \{1|\}$ then $1\equiv \{0|\}$ then $0$ and the sequence ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"whenever all left and right options of $G$ have this property" is vacuously satisfied if $G$ has no left or right options. Therefore by the hypothesis, $0$ has to satisfy the property, and so can never be chosen for this descending sequence.

Comment: Isn't 0 born on the first day and all games would lead to it?

Comment: I prefer to say that $0$ is born on the $0^{th}$ day, so that I'm pulling my ordinals from the present, not the future, but yes it is. However, that is exactly the point. Any such chain would lead to it, but it has to satisfy property $P$, and so cannot be in the chain. A contradiction, Therefore such a chain cannot exist.

Comment: @PaulSinclair the $0^{th}$ day! I have been thinking about a construction of the surreals that includes the $\varepsilon^{th}$ moment. Curious to find out more regarding "pulling ordinals from the present"!

Comment: @meowzz - The problem with i try's comment is that (in the construction referenced here) surreals *define* ordinals and "first" is a name for the ordinal $1$. Therefore to refer to the "day" that $0$ is born as "first" is to assign it an ordinal that has yet to be defined. That is why I prefer to label the "day" on which $0$ is born as the "$0^{th}$ day". As for "moments", please realize that "days" are just a convenient way to refer to the well-ordered collection of steps by which this construction defines the surreal numbers. Calling them "moments" instead doesn't change anything.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I understand $0th$ precedes $1st$ & that the "days" construction define the surreals. The "moments" construction would define the 'surhyperreal' or 'nonstandard surreals' [ eg. the $0th$ day has $\omega$ $\varepsilon$ moments ]

Comment: @meowzz - that was all I meant by my "pulling from the present, not the future" comment.